# Android ActionBar Icon and up indicator

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin

When trying to display the action bar up indicator it displays as a white blank square beside the icon. I have a custom theme for the action bar. Im trying to set the background as green and then the Icon with the up arro

[image]

in my Styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.Base.ActionBar</item>
```

```
<style name="Theme.Base.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@color/blue</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
<item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon</item>
```

At the top of my class i set the theme

```
         [Activity(Label = "My Activity", Theme = "@style/Theme.Base", NoHistory = true)]
public class Login : Activity
```

In my activity

```
        #region ActionBar MENU
    /// <summary>
    /// Creating the menu
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="menu">the menu to create</param>
    /// <returns>boolean</returns>
    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        var inflater = MenuInflater;
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.MapItems, menu);

        ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //Hide menu items you dont require
        menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.MyAccount).SetVisible(false);

        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On Menu Item Click
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="featureId">The feature Id</param>
    /// <param name="item">The item selected</param>
    /// <returns>boolean</returns>
    public override bool OnMenuItemSelected(int featureId, IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case (Constants.Home):
                StartNewActivity(typeof(Map.Map));
                break;
        }
        return base.OnMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: what is you up icon color? if it is white then change it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changes the image to a red square and I'm still getting the white space beside the home icon http://s22.postimg.org/7bbew7kgh/action_Bar_Red.png

Comment: use image for homeAsUpIndicator with background transparent not color,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't change the color but the white squarr is now gone. Removing the background set to white helped :-) and also setting the parent theme

```
parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">


 <style name="Theme.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.Base.ActionBar</item>
```

```
  <style name="Theme.Base.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@color/blue</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.Base.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
```